# Difference btn Restcomm CCA and GX resource adapters

Tags: restcomm, mobicents, diameter-protocol, jain-slee

I want to use a service to receive GX interface messages (Credit Control Request) but I found that CCA and GX RAs both are serving CCR with code 272 in restcomm (Mobicents) implementation.
I have below questions:

1. What is the difference between CCA resource adapter and GX resource adapter in restcomm jain-slee!?
2. So what is the right one that i should use?
3. Are implementations complied with 3GPP or IETF standards?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GX Restcomm implementation is based on  3GPP TS 29.210 V6.7.0 (2006-12) and it depends on  Diameter Credit-Control Application [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4006.txt) . However, the differences between CCA and GX Resource adapters:

1. CCA is configured to accept messages with:

   [Vendor-Id:0; Auth-Application-Id:4; Acct-Application-Id:0] and [Vendor-Id:10415; Auth-Application-Id:4; Acct-Application-Id:0] 
   **BUT** Gx accept messages with: [Vendor-Id:0; Auth-Application-Id:16777224; Acct-Application-Id:0], [Vendor-Id:10415; Auth-Application-Id:16777224; Acct-Application-Id:0] , [Vendor-Id:0; Auth-Application-Id:16777238; Acct-Application-Id:0] and [Vendor-Id:10415; Auth-Application-Id:16777238; Acct-Application-Id:0]
2. GX has more AVPs to be received.